# How to set the QLineEdit with new line

Tags: c++, qt

Currently I am copying the text to a LineEdit and on click PushButton it will write the text to a file which is "data.txt". I have written a `readfile()` which will read the text from data.txt and on click PushButton it should display the text in new line format at LineEdit.
Here is my code:

```
    void MainWindow::writefile()
    {
        QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
        QString filename = "data.txt";
        QFile file(filename);
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text);
        QTextStream out(&file);
        out<<str<<endl;
        file.close();
    }
    void MainWindow::readfile()
    {
        QString filename = "data.txt";
        QFile file(filename);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
        QTextStream  in(&file);
        QString str = in.readLine();
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(str);
        file.close();
    }
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    readfile();
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    writefile();
}
```

Please suggest how to separate those comma-separated strings and must display in new line format

[image: File Input Output]

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#details) says:

> A line edit allows the user to enter and edit a single line of plain text  [...]
>
> A related class is `QTextEdit` which allows multi-line, rich text editing.

Thus, you should use the [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) widget instead of `QLineEdit` to allow multi-line text. It also has a [`setText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setText), so you can use it the same way.

To replace commas with new line characters use the [`replace`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-8) method:

```
// ...

QString str = in.readLine();
str = str.replace(",", "\n");
ui->textEdit_2->setText(str);

//...
```